# Can I search through Serializer fields instead of Model Fields in ListAPIView?

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have a Serializer which has values from `OneToMany` and `ManyToOne` Relation.

```
class A(models.Model):
    abc = AnyField()
    bcd = AnfField()

class B(models.Model):
    xyz = ForeignKey(A)
    pqr = CharField()

class C(models.Model):
    lmn = ForeignKey(A)
    def = CharField()
```

My Serializers are as follows:

```
class BSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        fields = '__all__'

class CSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        fields = '__all__'

class ASerializer(ModelSerializer):
    B = SerializerMethodField()
    C = SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        fields = ('id', 'abc', 'bcd', 'B', 'C')

    def get_B(self, obj):
        return BSerializer(queryset=obj.b_set.all(), many=True).data

    def get_C(self, obj):
        return CSerializer(queryset=obj.c_set.all(), many=True).data
```

Now, In my views:

```
class AListView(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = ASerializer
    queryset = A.objects.all()
    search_fields = ('id', 'abc', 'bcd', 'B__pqr', 'C__def', )
```

I want to search in the serializer fields.
Is there a way, where I can search in `B`'s fields or 'C's fields.

Using `search_fields`, I can only search in `A`'s fields (`abc`, `bcd`).

Answer (score 0):

In order to search 'B__pqr' and 'C_def',  A model should be in OneToOne relation with B and C model. Or you need to keep a foreign key relation of B and C model in A model. What i want to say.

```
class A(models.Model):
    abc = AnyField()
    bcd = AnfField()
    B = Foreignkey(B)
    C = Foreignkey(C)
```

In this way you can able to search B's or C's property from A model.

### Edit for response:

Another possible solution is to overwrite the list and returning your expected response. But i must mention this is kind of hackish solution.

```
def list(self, request):
    # searching B_PQR
    PQR = self.request.query_params.get('BPQR', None)

    # searching C_DEF
    DEF = self.request.query_params.get('CDEF', None)

    if PQR:
        # customly randle your desire outcome and return
        # back response

    if DEF:
        # customly randle your desire outcome and return
        # back response

    queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())

    page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
    if page is not None:
        serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
        return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)

    serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
    // print here 
    print('response', serializer.data)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: Yup. I know that. I am asking if there's a way to search for `ManyToOne` fields as well?

Comment: @PrakharShrivastava then one of possible way but little bit hackish to overwrite listApiView 'list' function and return your desire search result. I have updated that portion in my code.

Comment: Yes, this what I'm doing right now. I thought that this seems to be a common scenario so maybe there must be a solution without handling the cases manually.
Thanks Anyway :-)